# Tikz: placing a node at the intersection of two circles along a hyperbola

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, intersections

I know one can use the intersection package to find the point of intersection but I don't understand how to do it yet.

I would like to label the increasing order of the intersections `F^*_2`, `F^*_1`, `F^*_m`. `F^*_1` (but over set with a ~), and `F^*_2` with the same over set.

**Note: I am ignoring the lower and upper most intersections.**

The code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle through extra radius/.code={% unorthodox addon for the through library
                                            % needs to be used after 'circle through'!
                                            % this can be avoided by slightly changing the source
  \tikz@addoption{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*(#1)}%
    \pgfset{/pgf/minimum width/.expanded=\pgf@tempa}%
  }%
}}
\tikzset{
  special style/.code={%
    \if#1\tikz@nonactiveexlmark
      \pgfkeysalso{@special style}%
    \else
      \pgfkeysalso{style/.expanded=#1}%
    \fi
  },
  @special style/.style={draw=none,fill=none}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style={font=\small},
  dot/.style={fill,outer sep=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=2pt,shape=circle,draw=none,label={#1}},
  dot/.default={}
]
\begin{scope}[rotate around ={-20.5560452:(1, -.75)}]
      \node[scale = .75, dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3cm, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, dot = {\(P_2\)}] (P2) at (-1, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, dot = {below: \(F\)}] (F) at (1cm, -.75cm) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.75!(P2)$) coordinate (half-center);
      \foreach \sStyle/\xFocus in {{draw, thick}/half}
        \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
          \foreach \sStyleR/\dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in
          {/.0cm, /.5cm, /1cm, /1.5cm}
          {
            \node[style/.expanded = \sStyle,
            special style/.expanded = {\sStyleR}] at (P\cPoint.center)
            ({\xFocus:\cPoint:\cRadius}) [circle through/.expanded =
            {(\xFocus-center)}, circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius] {};
            \global\let\cRadius\cRadius
         }

      \clip(-4, -5) rectangle (8, 5);
      \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red,
      thick] plot ({(-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
      {1.73 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

From my post [Tikz: drawing concentric circles with specified origins and the arc that connects the intersections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118185/15717)
Qrrbrbirlbel found the intersections with

```
\foreach \cSolution in {1,2}
    \foreach \cRadius in {1,...,3}
    \coordinate (i-\cRadius-\cSolution) at (intersection cs: first node={F:1:\cRadius}, second node={F:2:\cRadius}, solution=\cSolution);
```

but I am not clear on how to adapt the solution for my problem.

**Edit 1:**

I don't know if there is a smooth way to automate the process, but I have the middle point defined as:

```
\node[scale = .75, dot = {right:\(\overset{\mbox{~}}{F}_m^*\)}] (Fm)
      at ($(P1)!.75!(P2)$) {};
```

How can I make the the dot bigger and the overset `~` wont appear.  I have tried `\~` and `~` but nothing works.

**Edit 2:**

Close up of the output from Qrr.. answer:

The `\tilde` isn't overset and the node placement isn't similar.

[image]

**Edit 3:**

I was able to adjust some of the nodes but for the nodes along the hyperbola, if I adjust them more, the top nodes will be out of place.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = .7,
    every label/.append style = {font = \small},
    dot/.style = {fill, outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
      shape = circle, draw = none, label = {#1}},
    dot/.default =,
    small dot/.style = {minimum size = 2pt, dot = {#1}},
    small dot/.default =,
    big dot/.style = {minimum size = 3pt, dot = {#1}},
    big dot/.default =
  ]
    \begin{scope}[rotate around ={-23.9625:(.75, -1)}]
      \begin{scope}
        \clip(-2, -4) rectangle (0, 4);
        \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red, thick]
        plot ({(-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
        {1.73 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
      \end{scope}
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below, left = 3.5pt: \(P_2\)}] (P2) at
      (-1, 0) {};
      \node[scale = .75, small dot = {below, left = 3.5pt: \(F\)}] (F)
      at (.75, -1) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.75!(P2)$) coordinate (Fm) node[big dot =
      {below = 10pt, right = 3pt: \(F_m^*\)}] {};
      \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
        \foreach \sStyleR/\dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in
        {.0cm, .5cm, 1cm}
          \node[draw, thick] at (P\cPoint.center) (\cPoint: \cRadius)
          [circle through = (Fm), circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius]
          {};
      \foreach \cSolution in {1, 2}
        \foreach \cRadius in {1, 2}
          \node[black, big dot = {right = 2pt, below = 2pt:
            $\ifnum\cSolution = 2\expandafter\tilde\fi F^*_\cRadius$}]
          (n-\cRadius-\cSolution) at
          (intersection cs: first node = {1: \cRadius},
                            second node = {2: \cRadius},
                            solution = \cSolution) {};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I’m not so sure about the node placement issues you have. Of course, if you change the placement in the loops, *all* dots will be placed differently, you are going to either place the `\node`s outside of the loop or enhance the `\foreach` loops so that they use more than one variable. Should I update my answer giving you some ideas?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what do you mean by update your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same `\foreach` loop for the labeling:

```
\foreach \cSolution in {1,2}
  \foreach \cRadius in {1,...,2}
    \node[green,dot={right:$\ifnum\cSolution=2\expandafter\tilde\fi F^*_\cRadius$}]
         (n-\cRadius-\cSolution)
      at (intersection cs: first node={1:\cRadius},
                          second node={2:\cRadius},
                            solution=\cSolution) {};
```

The math behind the `intersection cs` seems to be a little bit un-precise, so I repeated the task with the `intersections` library.

(I also have cleaned up a little bit.)

### Code (`intersection cs`)

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle through extra radius/.code={% unorthodox addon for the through library
                                            % needs to be used after 'circle through'!
                                            % this can be avoided by slightly changing the source
  \tikz@addoption{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*(#1)}%
    \pgfset{/pgf/minimum width/.expanded=\pgf@tempa}%
  }%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style={font=\small},
  dot/.style={fill,outer sep=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt,shape=circle,draw=none,label={#1}},
  dot/.default=,
  small dot/.style={minimum size=2pt,dot={#1}},
  small dot/.default=,
  big dot/.style={minimum size=3pt,dot={#1}},
  big dot/.default=
]
\begin{scope}[rotate around ={-20.5560452:(1, -.75)}]
      \node[small dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3cm, 0) {};
      \node[small dot = {\(P_2\)}]        (P2) at (-1, 0) {};
      \node[small dot = {below: \(F\)}]   (F)  at (1cm, -.75cm) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.75!(P2)$) coordinate (Fm) node[dot={right:$F_m^*$}] {};
      \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
        \foreach \sStyleR/\dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in {.0cm, .5cm, 1cm, 1.5cm}
            \node[draw] at (P\cPoint.center) (\cPoint:\cRadius) [circle through=(Fm), circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius] {};
      \foreach \cSolution in {1,2}
        \foreach \cRadius in {1,2}
          \node[green,big dot={right:$\ifnum\cSolution=2\expandafter\tilde\fi F^*_\cRadius$}]
            (n-\cRadius-\cSolution) at (intersection cs: first node={1:\cRadius},
                                                        second node={2:\cRadius},
                                                           solution=\cSolution) {};

      \clip(-4, -5) rectangle (8, 5);
      \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red,
      thick] plot ({(-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
      {1.73 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`intersection cs`)

[image]

### Code (`intersections` library)

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,intersections}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle through extra radius/.code={% unorthodox addon for the through library
                                            % needs to be used after 'circle through'!
                                            % this can be avoided by slightly changing the source
  \tikz@addoption{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\pgf@tempa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}+2*(#1)}%
    \pgfset{/pgf/minimum width/.expanded=\pgf@tempa}%
  }%
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style={font=\small},
  dot/.style={fill,outer sep=+0pt,inner sep=+0pt,shape=circle,draw=none,label={#1}},
  dot/.default=,
  small dot/.style={minimum size=2pt,dot={#1}},
  small dot/.default=,
  big dot/.style={minimum size=3pt,dot={#1}},
  big dot/.default=
]
\begin{scope}[rotate around ={-20.5560452:(1, -.75)}]
      \node[small dot = {right: \(P_1\)}] (P1) at (3cm, 0) {};
      \node[small dot = {\(P_2\)}]        (P2) at (-1, 0) {};
      \node[small dot = {below: \(F\)}]   (F)  at (1cm, -.75cm) {};
      \path[blue] (F) edge (P1) edge (P2) (P1) edge (P2);
      \path ($(P1)!.75!(P2)$) coordinate (Fm) node[dot={right:$F_m^*$}] {};
      \foreach \cPoint in {1, 2}
        \foreach \dDeltaRadius[count = \cRadius from 0] in {.0cm, .5cm, 1cm, 1.5cm}
            \node[draw, name path global/.expanded=\cPoint:\cRadius] at (P\cPoint.center) (\cPoint:\cRadius) [circle through=(Fm), circle through extra radius = \dDeltaRadius] {};
      \foreach \cRadius in {1,2} {
        \tikzset{name intersections={of/.expanded={1:\cRadius} and 2:\cRadius,name/.expanded=n'-\cRadius}}
        \foreach \cSolution in {1,2}
          \node[green,big dot={right:$\ifnum\cSolution=2\expandafter\tilde\fi F^*_\cRadius$}] (n-\cRadius-\cSolution) at (n'-\cRadius-\cSolution){};
      }

      \clip (-4, -5) rectangle (8, 5);
      \draw [samples = 50, domain = -0.99:0.99, xshift = 1cm, red,
      thick] plot ({(-1 - (\x)^2) / (1 - (\x)^2)},
      {1.73 * (-2) * (\x) / (1 - (\x)^2)});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`intersections` library)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the dots a bit bigger?

Comment: @dustin Sure there is, I just have included `scale=.75` in the `dot` style. You can either use another `scale` factor or a different `minimum size`.

Comment: Also, my tilda appear offset to the left and not above.  Is there a package or something missing?  Last question, I tried using fill = white so the labels weren't overtaken by the lines but all that did was change the dot to white.  How can I clear that up as well?

Comment: I copied over that line from the post so I have `$\ifnum\cSolution = 2\expandafter\tilde\fi F^*_\cRadius$` but the tilde is still on the left and not above.  I just tried the fill = white.  It doesn't look as clean though.  Can LaTeX place the nodes near the dots in open white space automatically or would that need to be done individual?